# Como fazer este SELECT (SQL Server 2008)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2008

pra ser bem sincero não sei nem como começar a minha pergunta. Então vou primeiro colocar as informações que tenho.

Eu tenho a seguinte estrutura no meu banco de dados.

[image: Tabela A]

[image: Tabela B]

E preciso fazer um SELECT que me retorna o seguinte:

[image: Saída]

Como posso conseguir este resultado?

Comment: A pergunta não está completa. Falta informação para o seu entendimento.

Comment: Se a idéia é abrir cada coluna (3 adultos em adulto 1, 2 e 3) acho que seria o caso de mais do que um select. Eu escreveria uma lógica com TSQL ou a linguagem de programação da solução.

Comment: @P8Q qual informação você precisa para me ajudar?

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly como seria essa lógica? Estou sem ideias de como resolver este problema. Estou usando _SQL Server 2008_

Comment: @LeonardoRibeirodeAguiar aqui n consigo ver o que está abaixo de "Eu tenho" e de "Eu preciso". Vi que são duas imagens, mas elas n aparecem pelo menos aqui pra mim.

Comment: Unpivot   https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Utilize `INNER JOIN` com uma tabela qualquer de números:

```
CREATE TABLE NUMEROS (n INT);
INSERT INTO NUMEROS VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6);

SELECT 
  'Adulto ' + CAST(NUMEROS.n AS VARCHAR) AS PESSOA ,
  TabelaB.ValorAdulto AS VALOR
FROM TabelaA
INNER JOIN NUMEROS
  ON TabelaA.QtdAdulto >= NUMEROS.n
INNER JOIN TabelaB
  ON TabelaA.IDTabelaB = TabelaB.IDTabelaB
```

Saída:

```
|   PESSOA  | VALOR |
|-----------|-------|
|  Adulto 1 |   200 |
|  Adulto 2 |   200 |
|  Adulto 3 |   200 |
```

Agora basta utilizar o `UNION ALL` para as colunas `QtdCrianca`,`QtdBebe` e `QtdSenior`.

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8042c/7/0)

Comment: Usar um UNPIVOT pode ajudar também http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx